# How to monitor http metrics (such as response time or http status code) with Google monitoring stackdriver agent?

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I think I have a really simple use case:

- a **spring boot java application** that exposes metrics through an endpoint (localhost:8002/metrics) and through JMX
- a **google compute engine machine that hosts that application** (or a pod in Google Container Engine)

I want to have in the **monitoring dashboards simple metrics** exposed from spring boot (like http status code, http response time percentiles, etc..). In some way it's something really similar to what [appengine](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-appengine) offers, but on a GCE/GKE instance.

I tried to:

- configure a stackdriver agent with [jvm collector](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent-jvm) -> *PROBLEM: only basic jvm metrics are collected*
- configure a stackdriver agent with collectd plugins that retrieve my metrics and push to google cloud monitoring -> *PROBLEM: I got several errors because the agent cannot understand the collectd jmx/json plugins*
- pass through a Google Cloud Load Balancing -> *PROBLEM: apparently there are no metrics for that service*
- pass through a nginx server and configured a stackdriver agent with [nginx collector](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent-nginx) -> *PROBLEM: again only really basic metrics are collected*

So the real questions are:

- am I missing something or the only way is to go through **custom metrics**?
- apart from java/spring boot/etc .. Is anyone here that has applications running on Google Cloud and is **monitoring these kinds of metrics** with Stackdriver?

BTW: in case someone is interested to help, here is the [github repo](https://github.com/micheleorsi/stackdriver-custommetrics-spring-boot) where I am starting to make some experiments

Comment: Actually I just found this interesting doc: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#the_logentry_type. Probably the way to monitor such kind of things is with activity logs (and not directly with metrics!)